# How to filter a php object array

Tags: php, arrays, json, soap

I have a PHP Object array being returned to me from a SOAP request. I need to filter out all other data except the Air Quality Index and AqiDateTime object and value. All other data is not needed and actually creates an issue as I am needing this to be in an array that I am feeding for a graph plugin. The array is the values going to the plugin. Sorry if this is an easy question, I am the IT guy doing a web project.

Here is an example of the object as it's being seen from a var_dump

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
["CalculateSiteAQIByNaturalKeyJsonResult"]=>
object(stdClass)#3 (17) {
["AirQualityIndex"]=>
int(23)
["AqiDateTime"]=>
string(19) "2014-11-20T10:00:00"
["AqsUnitDescription"]=>
string(29) "Micrograms/cubic meter (25 C)"
["CategoryColorInteger"]=>
int(-16718848)
["CategoryDescription"]=>
string(4) "Good"
["FontColorInteger"]=>
int(-16777216)
["HealthAdvisory"]=>
string(4) "None"
["HealthEffects"]=>
string(4) "None"
["ParameterConcentration"]=>
float(24.67)
["ResponsibleAQIProgramID"]=>
string(36) "2d26a957-42f9-dd11-9b87-001e8c005352"
["ResponsibleAQIProgramName"]=>
string(4) "PM10"
["ResponsibleParameterID"]=>
string(36) "b8ab4bd9-89b0-4cdc-ba8a-3af9c038e5ba"
["ResponsibleParameterName"]=>
string(15) "PM10_(Standard)"
["SensitiveGroups"]=>
string(59) "People with respiratory disease are the group most at risk."
["SiteName"]=>
string(7) "BARSTOW"
["SourceSiteID"]=>
string(36) "3d104bd9-a9b7-e011-b9b9-444553544200"
["Unit"]=>
string(5) "UG/M3"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newArray = array(
     'AirQualityIndex' => $obj->CalculateSiteAQIByNaturalKeyJsonResult->AirQualityIndex,
     'AqiDateTime' => $obj->CalculateSiteAQIByNaturalKeyJsonResult->AqiDateTime);
```

Where `$obj` is the object returned from the SOAP call and $newArray is the new array to feed to the plugin.

The `->` is the object property access syntax in PHP.

In this case the CalculateSiteAQIByNaturalKeyJsonResult property on the parent object contains another object and the property access methods are chained. e.g.

`$obj->CalculateSiteAQIByNaturalKeyJsonResult->AirQualityIndex`

gives the Air Quality Index value.

Associative array syntax is an alternative way to access the properties. e.g.

`$obj['CalculateSiteAQIByNaturalKeyJsonResult']['AirQualityIndex']`

also will give the Air Quality Index value.

The `arrray(KEY => VALUE)` wrapper builds the new array.

See:http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php

Comment: This is leading me down the right path. I now getting a stdClass error though.

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$AirQualityIndex

Comment: # Test to get all Results in JSON from AQI API - Value used is aqiDateTime, setting it as PollTime variable.
$result = $client->CalculateSiteAQIByNaturalKeyJson($parameters);

var_dump ($result);

$newArray = array('AirQualityIndex' => $result->AirQualityIndex, 'AqiDateTime' => $result->AqiDateTime);

Comment: Thank you again for your help I really appreciate it. Sorry for the mass comments, I am new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

if the objects name is `$my_object`. you could store the information you want in an associative array like this:

```
$air_array = array();

$air_array['AirQualityIndex'] = $my_object->AirQualityIndex;
$air_array['AqiDateTime'] = $my_object->AqiDateTime;
```

Then `$air_array` has the info you want.

If you need the information to be an object, you can cast it as one like this:

```
$air_object = (object) $air_array;
```